# Метод обработчика недоступен. Откройте общий доступ или создайте аннотацию c помощью @FXML

Tags: java, javafx

Новичок, пытаюсь открыть другую сцену после нажатия на кнопку но почему то не хочет работать аннотация. Подозреваю что контроллер не имеет доступа к классу. В идеале, на даный момент, после нажатия кнопки должно закрыться или скрыться окно с логином и появится главное меню(буду рад совету как правильно это сделать или может где нибудь прочитать или я плохо еще знаю основы Java).

Собственно вот это кнопка в файле FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="tomain"  layoutX="517.0" layoutY="404.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#tomainmenu" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="Login" />
```

Контроллер:

```
@FXML
private void tomainmenu(Stage mainmenu) throws Exception {


    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Mainmenuui.fxml"));         ///// LOADING UI

    Scene mainmenuui = new Scene(root);
    mainmenuui.getStylesheets().add(Login.class.getResource("ef.css").toExternalForm()); ////// LOADING CSS

    mainmenu.setScene(mainmenuui);
    mainmenu.show();
}
```

Подозреваю что я все таки как то неправильно пытаюсь открыть новое окно, но за день уже надоело всматриваться в этот код.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш метод `tomainmenu` в качестве аргумента может нести либо ничего - `tomainmenu()`, либо эвент - `tomainmenu( ActionEvent ae )`, о `stage` ему ничего не известно.
Соответственно, присохраните `mainmenu`( допустим заранее передав с помощью сетера ) в полях класса и используйте по своему усмотрению:

```
private Stage mainmenu;

public void setMainMenu( Stage mainMenu ) {
    this.mainmenu = mainMenu;
}

@FXML
private void tomainmenu() {
    try {
         //ваш код
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

P.S. Для окошка логина советую посмотреть в сторону библиотеки `javafx.scene.control.Dialog`, примеров множество.